# Using Travis-CI for client-side JavaScript libraries?

Tags: javascript, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I'm not sure to use Travis-CI for my client-side JavaScript library or not, because it compiles with NodeJs on Travis-CI servers.

I want to know is this a good approach to use some kind of **continuous integration** such as Travis-CI for client-side libraries or not?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes of course you should use continous integration with client side libraries.

I personally use [PhantomJS (headless webkit browser)](http://phantomjs.org/) which is [already installed in Travis-CI](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/). I think this is the better option for client-side stuff than NodeJs.

If you use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), it gets even easier to use, all you need is a simple Gruntfile.js file, your tests that run in browser (I use [QUnit](http://qunitjs.com/)), and a simple .travis.yml

`Gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        qunit: {
            files: ['test/index.html']
        }
    });

    // Load plugin
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-qunit');

    // Task to run tests
    grunt.registerTask('test', 'qunit');
};
```

`.travis.yml`:

```
before_script:
  - sudo npm install -g grunt

script: grunt test --verbose --force
```

You can [see it in action](https://travis-ci.org/kort/kort/) at one of my projects ([source on GitHub](https://github.com/kort/kort)).

Comment: Wouldn't the mention of `grunt` as a `devDependency` in the package.json file, eliminate the need for the before_script part?

Comment: This is correct if you are using NPM to resolve dependencies. In my case I have a PHP project so I have to specify this dependency in the `before_script`

Comment: "see it in action" link is dead.

Comment: @gbmhunter you're right, I just fixed it. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: "see it in action" link is dead again.

Comment: I believe you also need `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-qunit');` for this to work. I see this in the [Gruntfile.js](https://github.com/kort/kort/blob/develop/Gruntfile.js#L60) for the repo you reference.

Comment: @danvk I think you're right, I added it to my example

Comment: `grunt.js` was changed to `Gruntfile.js` in 2013.  See https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/650

Answer (score 26):

I started with the answer from Odi and moved to gulp to get it working. If you specify node_js as your language in your travis file, travis will automatically run

```
npm install
```

followed by

```
npm test
```

The first will install any devDependencies specified in a package.json file, the second will run the script named "test" also from package.json. Below you'll find the three files I needed to have in the top level of my repo for travis to run a single qunit suite.

.travis.yml

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "0.10"
```

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    qunit = require('gulp-qunit');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    return gulp.src('./tests/unit/unittests_nupic-js.html')
        .pipe(qunit());
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "nupic-js",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "JavaScript port of NuPIC",
  "license": "GPL-3.0",
  "repository": "iandanforth/nupic-js",
  "bugs": { "url" : "http://github.com/iandanforth/nupic-js/issues"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "Ian Danforth",
    "email": "iandanforth@gmail.com"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "gulp"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "numenta",
    "nupic",
    "machine learning"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp-qunit": "~0.2.1",
    "gulp-util": "~2.2.14",
    "gulp": "~3.5.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Odi's answer updated and using npm to resolve dependencies:

**.travis.yml**

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "6"
```

---

**.Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    qunit: {
      files: ['./test/qunit.html']
    }
  });

  // Load plugin
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-qunit');

  // Task to run tests
  grunt.registerTask('test', 'qunit');
};
```

---

**Package.json** (relevant parts)

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-qunit": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  }
```

---

You can try the configuration locally by running `npm install` and then `npm test`.

Answer (score 1):

I found this example. Quite comprehensive!

https://github.com/jonkemp/gulp-qunit

run:

```
npm install
gulp test
```

It also has tasks for `lint` watching files, coverage reports and more.