# How to test a front-end JavaScript library and integrate with Travis?

Tags: javascript, integration-testing, frontend, travis-ci

I have already experimented testing NodeJS libraries using Jasmine or Mocha, but I don't know how to test front-end projects. I have found tutorials online, but everything includes a task manager in the workflow and I would like to know how to do this without one.

I found the following question close to what I am asking:

[Using Travis-CI for client-side JavaScript libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412211/using-travis-ci-for-client-side-javascript-libraries)

In my case, I am using Jasmine and have already set up the Jasmine `SpecRunner.html`, Jasmine library and `spec/mylibSpec.js`. The tests pass when I run the `SpecRunner.html` on my browser.

Now, how do I integrate this with Travis, **without** Grunt/Gulp/Brunch/etc?

I have heard the words "PhantomJS" and "Selenium" and I think this has to do with what I am trying to accomplish. Is there a "hello, world"-like project with tests and Travis integration one can learn from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Travis documentation [lists three basic ways](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/) to accomplish this:

1. the PhantomJS headless browser
2. running Firefox with a virtual display or
3. using the Saucelabs browser VM service

Testing with PhantomJS is the fastest, since it does not simulate a display (it still allows you to create screenshots, though). PhantomJS comes with a [run-jasmine example](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/run-jasmine.js).

The phantom test script can then be executed directly, simply by running

```
script: phantomjs run-jasmine.js
```

in your `.travis.yml`, without the additional overhead of a build system such as Grunt.

If testing your project requires a real browser GUI, that leaves you with options 2 or 3.

Saucelabs browser VMs have the advantage of real cross-browser testing; if your project is open source, they offer a [free plan](https://saucelabs.com/opensauce/). They also provide an in-depth tutorial for your specific use case: [Travis + Jasmine + Saucelabs](https://saucelabs.com/javascript/jasmine-js), which however does require Grunt in order to run.

Comment: Are there other services besides Travis that I could use? I can't believe this is such a dead-end? What is the best practice? What do people use at your cia?

Comment: @BubbleFever I don't quite understand - you specifically asked for Travis integration? What do you mean by 'dead end' and 'cia' ?

Comment: Right, but I think this is too hard. It should be simpler.